# Angular Error error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null' when calling scrollIntoView

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I'm working in an Angular project, and I want to make a scroll view in Angular by id. I wrote this method:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {



        if (this.router.url.includes('contact')) {
        let  abc ;
      abc=  document.getElementById("contact")
          abc.scrollIntoView();

        }
        if (this.router.url == '/') {
          window.scroll(0, 0)
        }



    }, 500);
  }
```

but I got the error of "object possibly null". I do not know what I should do

```
error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

21           abc.scrollIntoView();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById` possibly returns `null` (in case no element with such id exists in the DOM at query time) so you need to check if the query returned an element before calling methods on the result:

```js
let  abc = document.getElementById("contact");
if (abc !== null) {
    abc.scrollIntoView();
}
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#return_value

Answer (score 2):

ngAfterViewInit: A lifecycle hook that is called after Angular has fully initialized a component's view
ngOnInit: A lifecycle hook that is called after Angular has initialized all data-bound properties of a directive.

Try to put your code in AfterViewInit hook so that the dom which id is 'contact' is do rendered.

```js
ngAfterViewInit(){
  let abc = document.getElementById('contact');
  if(abc){
    abc.scrollIntoView();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you have to validate whether abc is null or not before calling `abc.scrollIntoView()`. You can either have the element in HTML or not, so Angular fires the error.

Try this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.router.url.includes('contact')) {
          let abc = document.getElementById('contact');
          if (abc) abc.scrollIntoView();
        }
        if (this.router.url == '/') {
          window.scroll(0, 0)
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the reason is the time you are running this code, your view is not completed and you are getting null. Instead try to get the scrollIntoView once your component view is initialised. Angular provides the hook and you should implement it like this:

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {

        if (this.router.url.includes('contact')) {
        let  abc = document.getElementById("contact");
         abc !== null ?  abc.scrollIntoView() : console.log('contact is not loaded');

        }
        if (this.router.url == '/') {
          window.scroll(0, 0)
        }

    }, 500);
  }
```